# Insert data into table where data in only two column varies

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, jdbctemplate

I have list of names and I need to insert into a table with a primary key which is auto generated and another three columns which will have the same data for each name. Is there any way to acheive this in single query?

```
| ID | Name | Age| Class|In-Charge|
|121 | Luc  | 12 | Five | 47855   |
|122 | Wayne| 12 | Five | 47855   |
|123 | Lih  | 12 | Five | 47855   |
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate of what you are trying to achieve with an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this where you `SELECT` the `name` from your list and the other values are just static values:

```
insert into yourtable (Name, Age, Class, [In-Charge])
select Name, 12, 'Five', 47855
from yourlist
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6029/1)